# How to write algorithms/pseudo-code in HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, html, latex

I'm used to writing [algorithms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms) in LaTeX while preparing my slides in Beamer but now I'm using an HTML presentation engine ([shower](https://github.com/shower/shower)) to prepare my slides. Are there any similar workflow/styles (css, javascript) to write algorithms
in HTML?

Answer (score 10):

I believe that there are plenty of them, but you can check [pseudocode.js](http://www.tatetian.io/pseudocode.js/).

> Pseudocode.js enables JavaScript to typeset algorithms as beautifullly as LaTeX does.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a ton (Baardzo dziekuje! :) )

Comment: This is excellent, and should be chosen as the "official" answer. Exceeds all expectations I had.

Comment: I'm trying to insert algorithms to my reveal.js slides but they're not rendered - it shows a blank slide. No error on the console, but the pseudocode test page is rendered correctly. Has anyone managed to insert algorithm to a slide? (<section> tag)

Comment: Looks like this link is broken, so here's the new one: https://saswat.padhi.me/pseudocode.js/

Answer (score 4):

You could check out [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), which renders LaTeX pretty nicely (at least insofar as math is concerned). I haven't done algorithms with it, though, so I can't say how well (or whether) it does them.

Comment: I write the math content using Mathjax but I seek writing algorithms actually.

Comment: MathJax does not have support for any algorithm environments.

Answer (score 0):

I think a lightweight solution like [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) is a good choice here. You can create dynamic layouts such as:

```
{{#if isActive}}
  <img src="star.gif" alt="Active">
{{else}}
  <img src="cry.gif" alt="Inactive">
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want algorithms in your HTML like conditions or such. You can use templating engines like Jade or Handlebars.

Jade: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade
Handlebars: http://handlebarsjs.com/